# Converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, converters

What am I doing wrong. When I run

```
insert into tblconfig_extensiongroupMembers (FKExtension,FKextensiongroup)
    values ('C7972F9-56SC-951S-CSRS-15VDAR4895W2','F15745S4-R512-45RD-84S0-5DSWW16A526W')
```

I get the following error conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier?

Comment: And what is the table definition?

Comment: Your first value only has 7 values in the first portion. It should be 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the format of your character string, it should be in the following format as specified at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187942.aspx):

> By converting from a string constant in the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, in which each x is a hexadecimal digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For example, 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid uniqueidentifier value.

**Working sample with 8 characters in first portion:**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp   (id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO #tmp
        ( id )
VALUES  ( '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012')

SELECT * FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

**Comparison of values:**

```
C7972F9-56SC-951S-CSRS-15VDAR4895W2  -- (Bad format)
12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 -- (Good format)
```

Comment: I did  end up fixing the hexadecimal part to the below info but still get the error: 

insert into tblconfig extensiongroupMembers (FKExtension,FKextensiongroup)
values ('C7972F9-4CBB-BCCE-8BF9E1097851','F49716C4-A318-45EC-89D0-2EDBB19A469E')

Answer (score 3):

Besides the length issue mentioned by others, the value should only contain  hexadecimal digits.

Your value contains invalid characters e.g. `S`, `R`, `W` and `V`.